# Extract table from web page by page

Tags: r, function, web, web-scraping, httr

I have written a code for web scraping table from webpage. This code extracts table from page one (in url /page=0):

```
url <- "https://ss0.corp.com/auth/page=0"
login <- "john.johnson" (fake)
password <- "67HJL54GR" (fake)

res <- GET(url, authenticate(login, password))
content <- content(res, "text")

table <- fromJSON(content) %>%
  as.data.farme()
```

I want to write a code to extract rows from table page by page and then to bind them. I do that, cause table is too large and i can't extract everything at once (it will brake the system). I don't know what how many pages there can be, it changes, so it must stop once the last page is collected. How could i do that?

Comment: Can you show what you did to extract page-by-page and to put the data together please.

Comment: When asking a question on SO, it helps to reduce the question to a minimal reprex. It looks like you've done that here (with sanitization) which is fine, but it needs to be code that actually *works*. This includes things like: (1) tell us any/all non-base packages you might be using, perhaps `dplyr` and `httr`; and (2) not have typos in your code, i.e., `as.data.farme`, that can cause doubt in your process. For this, though, have you tried a simple `for` loop or `lapply(seq_len(num_pages), function(pg) ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test to guarantee this will work because the question is not reproducible, but you mainly need three steps:

1. Setup the url and credentials

   ```
   url <- "http://someurl/auth/page="
   login <- ""
   password <- ""
   ```
2. Iterate over all (I'm assuming there are `N`) pages and store the result in a list. Note that we modify the url properly for each page.

   ```
   tables <- lapply(1:N, function(page) {
     # Create the proper url and make the request
     this_url <- paste0(url, page)
     res <- GET(this_url, authenticate(login, password))

     # Extract the content just like you would in a single page
     content <- content(res, "text")
     table <- fromJSON(content) %>%
       as.data.frame()
     return(table)}
   )
   ```
3. Aggregate all the tables in the list in a single complete table using `rbind`

   ```
   complete <- do.call(rbind, tables)
   ```

I hope this helps at least giving a direction.

Comment: it says Error in lapply(1:N, function(page) { : object 'N' not found

Comment: You have to assign the number of pages you want to iterate over to `N`.

Comment: but i don't know what it can be, it changes, so it must stop once the last page is collected